# Can't resolve dependencies for androidx.fragment:fragment-testing

Tags: android-fragments, gradle, android-testing, androidx

I'm want to try out the new androidx fragment testing library from 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing

In my `app/build.gradle` I add the dependencies as described in the docs

`debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0-alpha01'`

After syncing the project with gradle files I'm getting this error:

`Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0.`

Did I missed something there?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, in my Android Studio I have the wrong HTTP Proxy Configuration. Now everything works fine.